# Get a group of records by last unknown id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a log table where I want to select the entries for a specific group of records that are grouped by an id I don't know.
See the table below, there are more columns but these are not relevant for the question.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | details    | deviceId | processId | timestamp  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | startup    | 753      | 538       | 1546346190 |
| 2  | processing | 753      | 538       | 1546346192 |
| 3  | logging    | 753      | 538       | 1546346217 |
| 4  | done       | 753      | 538       | 1546346220 |
| 5  | startup    | 567      | 539       | 1590648690 |
| 6  | processing | 567      | 539       | 1590648692 |
| 7  | logging    | 567      | 539       | 1590648717 |
| 8  | done       | 567      | 539       | 1590648720 |
| 9  | startup    | 753      | 540       | 1590655888 |
| 10 | processing | 753      | 540       | 1590655890 |
| 11 | logging    | 753      | 540       | 1590655915 |
| 12 | email sent | 753      | 540       | 1590655918 |
| 13 | done       | 753      | 540       | 1590655920 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the last entries of one process for one device
When I query something like this I get all the records of the device:

```
SELECT *
FROM logtable
WHERE deviceId = 753
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

How can I only get the records with processId 540 in one query when I don't know the processId is 540?

I already tried it with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM logtable
WHERE processId IN (
   SELECT processId
   FROM logtable
   WHERE deviceId = 753
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC
   LIMIT 1
)
```

But MariaDB doesn't accept `LIMIT` in a subquery

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM logtable l
WHERE processId = (SELECT l2.processId
                   FROM logtable l2
                   WHERE l2.deviceId = 753
                   ORDER BY l2.timestamp DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

You only need `IN` if the subquery is going to return multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, this is the most frequently asked question under this tag. The standard solution is as follows:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM logtable x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT processId
            , MAX(timestamp) timestamp
         FROM logtable
        WHERE deviceId = 753
        GROUP
           BY processid
     ) y
    ON y.processid = x.processid
   AND y.timestamp = x.timestamp
```